# git equivalent for --all for all non-remote branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

The `--all` parameter is used in various git commands to refer to all branches. Is there an equivalent for all non-remote branches?

(Specifically, this came up using git-filter-branch, I'd like to work on all local branches.)

Comment: Please specify which commands you are talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** To the edit:

The following worked on a test repo with local and remote branches, rewriting only local branches:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --glob=refs/heads/*
```

(the `cat` tag name filter is just an example, obviously)

The `--glob` option is documented under **[man git-rev-parse](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)** for your information.

---

```
git branch
```

will already list all local branches.

Then, there is also

```
git for-each-ref -- --glob=refs/heads/*
```

for local refs

```
git for-each-ref -- --glob=refs/remotes/*/*
```

for remote refs